Data of waste managed through wastewater treatment plant in the U.S
for a research report, I have been looking for the total amount of waste (TW) managed through the wastewater treatment plant (WWT) in the U.S. for any of the last six years—an exhaustive search.
Looking for this data, I found the total amount of food waste (TFW) managed through WWT in 2018 & 2019 (U.S EPA  530-R-23-005, U.S EPA 2018 Fact Sheet), which is part of the TW.
Most solid waste is not suitable and will not go to WWT, and it is possible most food waste or other waste enters WWT via the sewer system. Is there any report or methodology to determine the TW numbers?

Are you looking for the total amount of wastewater treated in the US, or some kind of breakdown of the different types of waste contained in the wastewater?  Total wastewater treated seems to be easily available:
https://www.epa.gov/nutrientpollution/sources-and-solutions-wastewater#:~:text=Wastewater%20treatment%20facilities%20in%20the,and%20certain%20soaps%20and%20detergents.
